# R Jupyter: Error in checkInstall(models$library)

Tags: r, jupyter, r-caret

I am trying to train a model using the train() function from the caret package.
I am getting the following error:
[image]

But the library is already installed. I tried reinstalling the library but still getting the same error. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are both  "C50"  and "plyr" installed? Because both are needed for the "C5.0" method.

Comment: yes, both C50 and plyr are installed

Comment: what happens when you run library(C50)?

Comment: Error in library(C50): there is no package called ‘C50’.. But how? I have installed the library.

Comment: This fixed it..

install.packages('C50', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')